# MySQL: Select rows where a column is part of a given string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, wildcard

I search for a way to find a part of a given string in my table entries.
The field is varchar in table.

Search for

> /brands/brand/actona/kitchen-article/item/01945

and want to find this row:

```
/brands/brand/actona/$
```

-
or maybe this row

```
/brands/brand/actona/kitchen-$
```

Is there a way to solve this issue? The problem is that the table have at least 57k entries. I import the data from a old (too large) nginx-config file which are all permanent redirects.

Updated:
What I need a roughly the opposite of "LIKE", because just a part of the string i search for is stored in table with a wildcard ($), that can match also another string that starts with the same. `/brands/brand/actona/$` can match `/brands/brand/actona/123` but also `/brands/brand/actona/abc/def`.

So when I search for `/brands/brand/actona/abc/def` or even `/brands/brand/actona/abc/def/xyz` it need to match the row `/brands/brand/actona/$`

I actually try to outsource 57k permanent redirects from a nginx.config file to avoid checking a 6MB config file on each request.

I'm so sorry for my terrible english :(

Comment: Your quesiton isnt clear. What you want search, and where you are searching?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Take a look at `LIKE`.

Comment: What do you mean by column is part of a given string. Example you have given clearly shows that you want to find any matching values after `/brands/brand/actona/` so you should use `select * from table where column_name like '/brands/brand/actona/%';`. Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the `$` charater in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE '/brands/brand/actona/kitchen-article/item/01945'
LIKE CONCAT('%', URLCOLUMN, '%');
```

Comment: This wouldn't match the two examples given because of the $

Comment: Ah yes, I really have to ask OP the reason for the `$`, is it there as a regex operator? or is OP moneyfaced? xD

Comment: the $ is a wildcard.

Comment: What I need a roughly the opposite of "LIKE", because just a part of the string i search for is stored in table with a wildcard, that can match also another string that starts with the same. `/brands/brand/actona/$` can match `/brands/brand/actona/123` but also `/brands/brand/actona/abc/def`.

Comment: @leptoquark, what I gave you WILL WORK.

Comment: @LFlare nope it doesn't.

Comment: but this:
`SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 table
WHERE 
 SUBSTRING(source_uri, -1) = '*' AND
 '/brands/brand/actona/kitchen-article/item/01945' LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING(source_uri, 1, LENGTH(source_uri)-1), '%');`

Comment: * = $ I changed that

Comment: @leptoquark There's no need to have `$` in your search string. Without the `$`, my code will work.

Comment: I honestly do not understand, `%` is the wildcard operator in MySQL, if you follow my solution and omit the `$` from the URL, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
column REGEXP '(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+\$?'
```